# Ignore an exception in Twig template

Tags: exception, symfony, twig

I have a template `area.html.twig` that renders another template:

```
//area.html.twig
...

{% render 'Acme:User:restricted.html.twig' %}

...
```

Is there a way to ignore\catch an exception that was thrown by `restricted.html.twig` and just render nothing instead?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to catch exceptions in Twig. Anyway, you **should not** handle exceptions in frontend. You have to handle it in your action. P.S. Are you trying to render template? You should `render` controller's action. Did you mean `include`?

Comment: I'm rendering a controller's action. That action is only rendered to some of the users and I wanted the action to check for permission and throw an exception if the user is not authorized to see it. I can't check in the template itself because it's not just a `is_granted` check.. I want it to throw an exception because it's used in other forms as well (standalone, ajax, etc..)

Comment: Have you thought about implementation of your own twig filter or function, and putting all needed logic there?

Comment: But that'll just do double checks (in the twig function and then in the action).. is creating my own try...catch tag complicated?

Answer (score 7):

You should use [embedded controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) in your template:

```
{% render "yourBundle:Controller:action" with { 'data': data, } %}
```

better do this with a route (as of [symfony security update](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-symfony-2-0-20-and-2-1-5-released)):

```
{% render url('theactionroute', { 'data': data }) %}
```

In the action you can check for whatever you want and return a blank response / template for some circumstances.

You can also wrap your template rendering in a try & catch block and return a error template in case of an twig exception:

```
      try {
           $response =  $this->render('yourBundle:Default:action.html.twig',
                                      array('data' => $data));
      } catch (\Exception $exc) {
           return $this->render('yourBundle:Default:error.html.twig', array(
                        'message' => $exc->getMessage()
                    ));
      }
```